# How to access name of file within fs callback methods?

Tags: node.js, asynccallback, fs

How do I get access to the the arguments of [`fs.read`,`fs.stat`...](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) methods from within a callback?

For instance if I want to process a file based on its size
Following (coffeeScript) code snippet

```
#assuming test1.txt exists
filename = "./test1.txt"
fs.stat filename, (err, stats) ->
  data = filename:filename,size:stats.size
  console.log data
  #further process filename based on size
filename = "./test2.txt"
```

prints

```
{ filename: './test2.txt', size: 5 }
```

as filename is set to "./test2.txt". If I process/read the file using filename variable within  `fs.stat` callback it would use `test2.txt` which is not intended.

What I expect to see within callback is

```
{ filename: './test1.txt', size: 5 }
```

Comment: Node.js is asynchronous. The callback is invoked after the filename var is set to `./test2.txt`.

Comment: @RyanOlds I know why It prints test2.txt, But What I want to know is if there is any way to access  `"./test1.txt"` from within callback

Comment: Wrap the `filename` and the `fs.stat` call in a function and take advantage of function scope.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vLbVC/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't think there's a way to do this right now. Might be a good thing to add to node at some point. If you're going to do this a lot you can put `fs.stat` in a friendly wrapper.

```
var friendlyStat = function(filename, callback){
    fs.stat(filename, function(err, stats){
        stats.filename = filename

        if(err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(err, stats);
        }
    })
}

friendlyStat('test1.txt', function(err, stat){ console.log(stat.filename);});
friendlyStat('test2.txt', function(err, stat){ console.log(stat.filename);});
```

Comment: the answer was missing the `)` for the `fs.stat`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the synchronous `fs.statSync()` function if you can afford that, and that would help with your issue.

```
var filename = 'test1.txt';
var stat = fs.statSync(filename);
//code you were writing in callback comes here like the below:
console.log('Is ' + filename + ' a directory? ' + stat.isDirectory());
//Outputs 'Is test1.txt a directory? false'
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works great, but here's a solution I came up with when I wanted to loop through an array of files:

```
var files = [ 'path/to/file1.txt', 'path/to/file2.txt'],
    callback = function( filepath ) {
        return function( error, stat ) {
            console.log( filepath );
            console.log( error );
            console.log( stat )
        };
    };

    for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
        fs.stat( files[ i ], callback( files[ i ] ) );
    }
```

We're calling the `callback` function and passing it the filename as an argument. The function then returns the actual callback function which is used by `fs.stat`.