# How to run a function in a fs.stat callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, fs

Im using npm papercut https://www.npmjs.com/package/papercut for image upload and this is the function that saves an image(works perfect).

```html
uploader.process('image1', file.path, function(images){
  console.log(images.avatar); // '/images/uploads/image1-avatar.jpg'
  console.log(images.small); // '/images/uploads/image1-small.jpg'
})
```

And Im using File System Module method `fs.stat` and I want to create a directory and I want the `uploader.process` to run inside the `fs.stat` callback. so the images that get save go into the directory that `fs.stat` creates. This is the code that I have so far i don't know where to put `uploader.process` function so the callback calls it.

```js
fs.stat(`${tenantId}/`, function (err, stats){
  if (err) {
    // Directory doesn't exist or something.
    console.log('Folder doesn\'t exist, so I made the folder ' + `${tenantId}/`);
    return fs.mkdir(`assets/${tenantId}`, callback);
  }
  uploader.process('image1', file.path, function(images){
   console.log(images.avatar); // '/images/uploads/image1-avatar.jpg'
   console.log(images.small); // '/images/uploads/image1-small.jpg'
  })

});
```

Comment: This answer helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659054/how-to-access-name-of-file-within-fs-callback-methods

Comment: Where `file` variables comes from? Why are you returning after create the folder, don't you want to process the image after the folder is created? Some code is missing, is this inside a router handler?

Comment: @MiguelLattuada `file` comes from a variable I have outside this function which is `var file = req.files`, and Im returning `uploader.image` after creating the folder because that is my question I don't know where to put it so the callback can call that function.And the only code that im missing is code for the `uploader.image` which I didn't think I need to add my question was on the `fs.stat` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices, make your calls synchronous. Or use promises. (Maybe you have other choices but I hope these would help).

```js
// Synchronous way

// Check for node docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path
const stats = fs.statSync(`${tenantId}/`);

// Check for stats class def: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats
if (!stats.isDirectory()) {
  // Node docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode
  fs.mkdirSync(`assets/${tenantId}`);
}

uploader.process('image1', file.path, function(images){
   console.log(images.avatar); // '/images/uploads/image1-avatar.jpg'
   console.log(images.small); // '/images/uploads/image1-small.jpg'
});

// Async way

fs.stat(`${tenantId}/`, (err, stats) => {
  const localPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (err) {
      fs.mkdir(`assets/${tenantId}`, () => { resolve(true) });
    }
    resolve(true);
  });
  
  localPromise.then(result => {
    uploader.process('image1', file.path, function(images){
     console.log(images.avatar); // '/images/uploads/image1-avatar.jpg'
     console.log(images.small); // '/images/uploads/image1-small.jpg'
  });
  });
});
```

Check the docs, probably you should try/catch the mkdir in both cases async/sync.